# Need to render Routes component only once while keeping conditional rendering of layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So my app has a home page and some nav links. The navbar isn't visible on the home page but it's visible on everything else. The way I did it is by checking the `location.pathname` and if it's not `/` I'll render the routes with a navbar and inside a specific page layout which is made only for the inner pages and not the home page.

Like this:

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation()

  return (
      <Layout>
        {
          location.pathname !== "/" ? 
          <PageLayout>
            <NavBar /> 
            <DefaultRoutes />
          </PageLayout> :
          <DefaultRoutes />
        }
        
      </Layout>
      
  );
}
```

Default routes:

```
const DefaultRoutes = () => {
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
      </Routes>
    );
};
```

This works, however, I want to incorporate some exit animations between **all** routes, and they currently only work within every other link other than `/` because the `<DefaultRoutes/>` component is unmounted and mounted again every time I go to the home page. My question is how do I render the `DefaultRoutes` component only once while keeping the functionality of the navbar and layout for specific routes

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by just creating a wrapper/layout element called `NavLayout` and then nesting my nav routes inside it

```
const NavLayout = () => {
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <NavBar />
      <Outlet />
    </PageLayout>
  )
}
```

Routes:

```
const DefaultRoutes = () => {
  
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<NavLayout />}> 
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    );
};
```

Now there is no conditional rendering and i just render `<DefaultRoutes />` once in App.